# how to find log on web in a specific format

Tags: web, data-mining, text-mining

I making a data mining software that discovers intrusion of web application or others.
This software works by examine access log of a web site and find outliers, pattern that not represent an usual behavior.

Now for test my software I need of some access.log or other web log that have in a row this syntax:

```
- - - [06/Jan/2009:06:46:07 +0000] "GET /lostpasswd.php?env=myobject ..... etc.. HTTP/1.1" 200 43  etc...
```

my software search pattern after `.php?` and take the element after the symbol "=" it stops when reach `HTTP`

So where can  I find this kinds of access log ?? 
I try to search with google using this :
`inurl:access.log filetype:log`

but often results aren't good for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache, these files are usually located under /var/log/  but this is a restricted area and would have to be runned from the machine as an administrator or piped to your  executable. Here is the link to apaches log documentation. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

hoping this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a friend who has an own website? He could probably provide you with some logs.

Note that the actual patterns will be *very* much site dependant. In fact, when you collect enough logs, you might end up actually mining only trivial patterns (e.g. no parameters) and actual attack patterns (for trivial attacks; there are thousands of so called "script kiddies" trying years old exploits on thousands of web servers without success).

Plus, you'll produce tons of false alerts. There are broken links, browser errors, badly written spiders. You'll detect all these much more often than a proper attack.

You really need to get a cooperation with some bigger web site that is actually attacked from time to time, to validate your results.